# Converting a stripped string into an interger?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace, int

I'm trying to strip a string from all text and turn it into an integer so that I can use if statements on it easier...

#### Example:

```
count = "19 Count"
count = count.replace(" Count", "")
print repr(count)
print int(count)
```

#### Example Output:

```
'19'
19
```

However in my actual code my output is:

#### Real Output:

```
u'19'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 153, in <module>
    print int(count)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: I have tried the code and the output is what you expected

Comment: Are you reading from a file in your *actual code*?

Comment: @Christian Like I showed in my post, my example output shows `'19'` and `19` but in my real code it shows it differently.

Comment: What is the type of the `count`? Did you try `int(repr(count))`?

Comment: Im using python 2.7.3 I copy-pasted your code and it works fine, why could it be different?

Comment: @Christian I'm confused as to how you don't understand my problem, the example code works fine, my real code doesn't work. repr outputs: `u'19'`

Comment: @Hyflex `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` means that, the input passed to `int` funciton is `''`. Can you show the piece of code which actually throws this error?

Comment: I got it now, but could you give us some extra information of your real code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` is you are passing empty string in `int()`. Like `int('')`. The **main problem is in the code which strips the non-digit characters**.

Regex can be used to get first digits.

```
In [3]: import re

In [4]: a = re.search('\d+', ' 18 count 9 count')

In [5]: int(a.group())
Out[5]: 18
```

Comment: Any ideas for: `count = "19 Count 1 Count"` I only want the first set of numbers in this example, `19` when I tried using sub made my number `191`

Answer (score 2):

Checking digit for every word and used [Filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) to output if it it's true.

```
>>> count = "19 Count"
>>> filter(lambda x:x.isdigit(), count)
'19'
```

Comment: No need for `lambda`: `filter(str.isdigit, count)`. However this solution only works in python2, because in python3 `filter` always return an iterable and not a sequence(in particular, not a sequence of the same type as the argument).

Comment: @Bakuriu `TypeError: descriptor 'isdigit' of 'str' object needs an argument`

Comment: @Hyflex I added the explain. I hope it's help you understanding. :)

Comment: @PuffinGDI Any idea how I would get around this problem then: `count = "19 Count 1 Count"`, I only want the first set of numbers which is 19 in this example, everything else should be discarded.

Comment: @Hyflex If you get that error it means that you did **not** read my comment correctly. It's `filter(str.digit, count)` *not* `filter(str.digit(), count)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, to meet your requirements.  Will only match the first "set of numbers":

```
import re
regex = re.compile("(\d+)")
r = regex.search("19 Count 1 Count")
print(int(r.group(1)))
```

Output:

```
19
```

You can try out the code here: http://ideone.com/OwbMYm